# Error with Insertion Sort Python

Tags: python, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm trying to implement insertion sort with python. This is my code:

```
def insertionSort(lst):
    lstSorted = [lst[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        index = len(lstSorted)-1
        while index >= 0:
            if lst[i] > lstSorted[index]:
                lstSorted.insert((index+1),lst[i])
            else:
                lstSorted.insert(index,lst[i])
            index -= 1
    return lstSorted



def main():
    lst = [100,10,10000,1000,1000000,10000]
    sortedLst = insertionSort(lst)
    print(sortedLst)

main()
```

This is the output:

```
[10, 10000, 10000, 1000000, 1000, 10000, 10000, 1000000, 1000, 10000, 10000, 1000000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 1000000, 100, 10000, 10000, 1000000, 1000, 10000, 10000, 1000000, 1000, 10000, 10000, 1000000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 1000000]
```

I realize that there is an error with my "index-=1", but I'm not sure how to fix it. This is a problem when it gets to:

```
10, 100, 10000
```

the while loop is never broken out of because index is at 0, so the while loop runs again so it becomes:

```
10, 10000, 100, 10000
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What's Happening is, Every time you do an `if` and it passes, it will insert the element before it.
Try this,

```
def insertionSort(lst):
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        j = i
        while j > 0:
            if lst[j-1] > lst[j]:
                t=lst[j]
                lst[j]=lst[j-1]
                lst[j-1]=t
            j-= 1
    return lst

def main():
    lst = [100,10,10000,1000,1000000,10000]
    sortedLst = insertionSort(lst)
    print(sortedLst)

main()
```

What you were doing is if element in lst is greater than element in lstSorted you were inserting lst element after lstSorted element.But if it is less you were adding it before the element in lstSorted and then decrementing the index and again comparing.
So if the list is `[5,4,3]`
First loop lstSorted becomes `[4,5]`
But second loop it becomes `[3,4,3,5]`
What you will have to do is select appropriate location to put in `lst[i]` and only then insert it there.

So if you want separate list then you can modify your script to

```
def insertionSort(lst):
    lstSorted = [lst[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        index = i-1
        while index >= 0:
            if lst[i] > lstSorted[index]:
                lstSorted.insert((index+1),lst[i])
                break
            index -= 1
        if index==-1:
                lstSorted.insert(0,lst[i])
    return lstSorted

def main():
    lst = [100,10,10000,1000,1000000,10000]
    sortedLst = insertionSort(lst)
    print(sortedLst)

main()
```

Comment: While this code is correct, it also changes the question's code to modify the passed in list in-place, rather than returning a new list. That may or may not be desirable (compare `list.sort` with `sorted`).

Comment: Ya. You are right. I have edited my answer for that case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that you're repeatedly inserting the same value into your sorted list in your `while` loop. You only want to insert once (per cycle of the `for` loop), so you need to change your logic a little.

The simplest change would be to add a `break` after the first `insert` call, and then move the `else` block from the `if` to the `while` loop (and change the index of the insertion to `0`). This uses a relatively unusual feature of Python, that loops can have `else` blocks that run only if the loop ran to completion without a `break` statement being hit.

```
def insertionSort(lst):
    lstSorted = [lst[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        index = len(lstSorted)-1
        while index >= 0:
            if lst[i] > lstSorted[index]:
                lstSorted.insert(index + 1, lst[i])
                break     # stop the while loop after inserting
            index -= 1
        else:             # if we reached index -1 without breaking, insert at the start
            lstSorted.insert(0, lst[i])
    return lstSorted
```

You might notice though that the `insert` at index `0` is actually still `index+1`, just like the other insert call, so we could in fact combine both cases into a single one. I think this is quite a bit more elegant:

```
def insertionSort(lst):
    lstSorted = [lst[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        index = len(lstSorted)-1
        while True:   # loop until a break is reached
            if index < 0 or lst[i] > lstSorted[index]:   # combine both insert cases
                lstSorted.insert(index + 1, lst[i])
                break
    return lstSorted
```